# To display characters in reverse order using nasm [infinite loop running]

Tags: nasm

THE PROGRAM IS USED TO ACCEPT CHARACTERS AND DISPLAY THEM IN REVERSE ORDER

The code is included here:

```
section .bss           
    num resb 1

section .text          
    global _start

_start:                
    call inputkey
    call outputkey

    ;Output the number entered
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

inputkey:
    ;Read and store the user input
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, num  
    mov edx, 1         
    int 80h

    cmp ecx, 1Ch
    je .sub2
    push ecx
    jmp inputkey

.sub2:
    push ecx
    ret

outputkey:
    pop ecx
    ;Output the message
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    ;mov ecx, num
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h  

    cmp ecx, 1Ch
    je .sub1
    jmp outputkey

.sub1:
    ret
```

The code to compile and run the program

> logic.asm

is given here:

> nasm -f elf logic.asm
>
> ld -m elf_i386 -s -o logic logic.o
>
> ./logic

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the code. Firstly, for the `sys_read` syscall (eax = 3) you supplied 2 as the file descriptor, however 2 refers to `stderr`, but in this case you'd want `stdin`, which is 0 (I like to remember it as the non-zero numbers 1 and 2 being the output).

Next, an important thing to realize about the `ret` instruction is that it pops the value off the top of the stack and returns to it (treating it as an address). Meaning that even if you got to the `.sub2` label, you'd likely get a segfault. With this in mind, the stack also tends to not be permanent storage, as in it is not preserved throughout procedures, so I'd recommend just making your buffer larger to e.g. 256 bytes and increment a value to point to an index in the buffer. (Using a fixed-size buffer will keep you from getting into the complications of memory allocation early, though if you want to go down that route you could do an external `malloc` call or just an `mmap` syscall.)

To demonstrate what I mean by an index into the reserved buffer:

```
section .bss
    buf resb 256

; ...

inputkey:
    xor esi, esi ; clear esi register, we'll use it as the index

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0 ; stdin file descriptor
    mov edx, 1 ; read one byte

.l1: ; loop can start here instead of earlier, since the values eax, ebx and edx remain unchanged
    lea ecx, [buf+esi] ; load the address of buf + esi
    int 80h

    cmp [buf+esi], 0x0a ; check for a \n character, meaning the user hit enter
    je .e1
    inc esi
    jmp .l1

.e1:
    ret
```

In this case, we also get to preserve `esi` up until the output, meaning that to reverse the input, we just print in descending order.

```
outputkey:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1 ; stdout
    mov edx, 1

.l2:
    lea ecx, [buf+esi]
    int 80h

    test esi, esi ; if esi is zero it will set the ZF flag
    jz .e2:
    jmp .l2

.e2:
    ret
```

*Note:* I haven't tested this code, so if there are any issues with it let me know.